# How to determine which type of DOM element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code:

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input, #product-create-step-2 img').each(function() {             
  // I should check here if element is input or img
  // If element is input I should get $(this).val()
  // If element is img I should get $(this).attr('src')
  var type = $(this).attr("type");
  if ((type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") && $(this).is(":checked")) {
    inputValues[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
  } else if (type != "button" || type != "submit") {
    inputValues[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
  }
});
```

How do I check which type of DOM element I have in order to get the correct values?

I know there is a function :is()in jQuery but the example taken from SO: Finding the type of an element using jQuery is for one element and not for a list.

**UPDATE**

This is the code I'm working on:

```
var inputValues = [];
$('#product-create-step-2 input, #product-create-step-2 img').each(function(i, e) {
    e = $(e);

    if (e.is("input")) {
        var type = $(this).attr("type");
        if ((type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") && $(this).is(":checked")) {
            inputValues[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        }
        else if (type != "button" || type != "submit") {
            inputValues[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
        }
    } else if (e.is("img")) {
        inputValues[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr()
    }
});
```

But I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: e is undefined

Why?

**SOLUTION**

Finally and after test all the solutions I go trough Joe, here is the result (feel free to made any suggestions about it)

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input, #product-create-step-2 img').each(function(i, e) {
    var that = $(this);
    var thatis = this.src || this.value;
    inputValues[that.attr('id')] = thatis;
});
```

Comment: what about the `get(0)`, have you checked that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using this:

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input, #product-create-step-2 img').each(function() {        
    var myVar = this.value || this.src;
});
```

Note: `src` *is* a valid attribute of some input types so this will only work if none of your inputs have that attribute set. Otherwise this will work perfectly as `img` doesn't have a `value` attribute and (most) inputs don't have a `src`.

If some of your inputs *do* have the `src` attribute then take a look at Logan's answer.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kerf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Like so

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input, #product-create-step-2 img').each(function(e) {             
    e = $(this);
    if(e.is("input")) {
        console.log(e.val());
    } else if(e.is("img")) {
        cosole.log(e.attr("src"));
    }
});
```

Comment: @Reynier what version of jquery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use typeof(N) to get the actual object type.

To get element tag name use elem.tagName or elem.nodeName.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    $('#product-create-step-2 input, #product-create-step-2 img').each(function(i) {             
        var thisElem = $(this);
        if(thisElem.is("input")) {
            //get its val
        } else if(thisElem.is("img")) {
            //gets its src
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you sure? e isn't even being referenced inside the each function so I cant see how that is happening

Comment: e is just a reference to the index of the element you are passing over, it would probably be better to name it I or index actually, i'll edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
$('#product-create-step-2 input, #product-create-step-2 img').each(function() {             

  var isImage= $(this)..get(0).tagName == "IMAGE";
var isInput = $(this)..get(0).tagName == "INPUT";
  if (isImage) {
    var requiredval = $(this).attr('src');
  } else if (isInput ) {
   var requiredval = $(this).val();
  }
});
```